# I need plugin which can make my each unique employee upload his work

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I need plugin which can make my each unique employee upload his work like only media or client can submit job requirement with only 3 field title ,media,description without login into wordpress dashboard like this http://web1expert.com/test/client-submission-form/  & each client is redirected to dat work without login into dashboard

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad topic to be discussed here. Be more specific if you are facing any particular issues.

Or you can use Upwork for posting this job to hire someone to complete it up.

Answer (score -1):

try (visual form builder)
with this plugin you can create field with file upload field
but this is not Exactly what you want

Comment: ya i dnt want thm 2 access backend & i dnt want them 2 register